# Scott Aspect 700/900 frames

Tags: mountain-bike, frames

Do I understand correctly that Scott Aspect 700/900 series use the same frame and the difference between the 910 and 960 are in other components?

https://www.scott-sports.com/global/en/product/scott-aspect-910-bike?article=265276008
https://www.scott-sports.com/global/en/product/scott-aspect-960-blue-orange-bike?article=265284009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the lower to mid range bikes I believe they use Alloy for all frames.

900/910/920 in some ranges (e.g. Scale and Spark) are Carbon and there are a couple of different frames in these high end products, so you need to do homework to know the differences. Lower end bikes such as 960 are Alloy, which I understand is the same frame speced with different components.

In the soft tails - such as the Spark, the mid range use an alloy rear triangle and carbon main frame.

Answer (score 2):

The pages you linked to both say "700/900 Alloy Frame", and they look identical in geometry and tube sizes, so they are very likely functionally the same.

I notice the higher spec bike has internal cable routing though.

Update: after a closer look at the pictures of the bikes, several small differences can easily be seen, in addition to the internal cable routing.

Comment: My bad, I initially compared 950 to 910, did not notice that 960 does not have internal cable routing. 910 to 950 have the same frame description, though.